# How to get the message body from PHPMailer?

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I use PHPMailer to send email via SMTP. It works, but it doesn't save the sent emails in

`sent items`. I want to make to sent emails in the `sent items`, any idea?

I know can use `imap_append` function to achieve it. But, how to do that?

The PHPMailer seems doesn't has the function to return the $message.

```
if ($return = $mail->Send()) {

$stream = imap_open("{{$host}:993/imap/ssl}Sent Items", $user_name, $user_pwd); 

imap_append($stream, "{{$host}:993/imap/ssl}Sent Items" , $message  , "\\Seen");

imap_close($stream);

};
```

How to get the message body from PHPMailer?

Comment: First of all PHPMailer doesn't have anything to do with IMAP actions you want to achieve so i think you might want to consider changing the title of this post. Second is, i don't really get what the exact problem is. Do you have problems with getting the message body from PHPMailer or is there something wrong with the actual IMAP actions you want to execute?

Comment: yes, I'd like to know how to getting the message body from PHPMailer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The instance variables from PHPMailer are all public.
Looking at the source you can just use:

```
$mail->Body
```

If you want the plain body including the all boundaries you could also use:

```
$mail->CreateBody();
```

See:
http://phpmailer.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/phpmailer/trunk/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php?revision=452&view=markup

Answer (score 0):

> The PHPMailer seems doesn't has the function to return the $message.

Yes, it does. At least in version 5.2.28 there is a method `getSentMIMEMessage()` to get the full MIME message (different from the *email* body). That method only works after sending the email, or calling the `preSend()` method.